# Is there a way to automatically remove ngons?

Tags: mesh

[image][image]As you can see, I am trying to make a computer screen, but am wondering how I can make my mesh of a screen correctly connect to the main frame. Do I have to manually use the knife tool? Or is there a better option? Thanks for all advice or suggestions!

The first picture is the subdivision gone wrong.
The second picture shows my original mesh.
[image]

Comment: Add to main body as many loopcuts (CTRL+R) as vertices on perimeter of "screen part". Then delete ngons, select edges and create W -> "edge bridge loop".

Comment: Thanks! I tried that, but it covered up part of the screen that it connected to. Will update pictures to show problem. See how the screen full of many edges is reduced when I do the edge bride loop? Probably am doing something totally wrong.

Comment: Did you try converting your selection to tris and then converting to quads ?

Comment: Um no. So I need to convert the selection to tris, then to quads? I thought the default was always quads. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Seems you have deleted Ngon not as face but as vertices, thus reduce geometry.

Comment: Cut your screenshots only to relevant area please, it's much more complex to preview them when they are that big and containing something not related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From left to right:

1. Add loopcuts <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Number of loopcuts = number of vertices (I marked them with blue dots) except those in the corners, because they already have a proper connection.
2. Select and delete Ngons: <kbd>Delete</kbd>->*Faces*. Select edges
3. Press <kbd>W</kbd>-> *Edge Bridge Loops*

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to do the loopcuts and edge bridge loops in pieces, whereas you show how to do it all at once. Now it works! Thanks!